# AttributeError: 'LogInPage' object has no attribute '_frame'

Tags: python, tkinter

I was adding a simple Login, but when I put `login_user` as function, I got some problems with the next Frames on Tkinter.

There is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font as tkfont  # python 3
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import  *
from tkinter.constants import FALSE

OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path("./assets")
def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
     return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
     def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        logo = PhotoImage(file=ASSETS_PATH / "LOGO.png")
        self.title("ACURANZ")
        self.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self._w, logo)
        self.geometry("892x549")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(LogInPage)

     def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()
class LogInPage(tk.Frame):
     user = 'asper'
     passw ='asper'
     
     def __init__(self, parent):
         tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = Canvas(
            bg = "#F1F2F2",
            height = 549,
            width = 892,
            bd = 0,
            highlightthickness = 0,
            relief = "ridge"
        )

        self.canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
     
        self.entry_1 = Entry(
            bd=0,
            bg="#FFFFFF",
            highlightthickness=0
        )
        self.entry_1.place(
            x=503.0,
            y=239.0,
            width=170.0,
            height=28.0
        )

        self.entry_image_2 = PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("entry_2.png"))
        entry_bg_2 = self.canvas.create_image(
            588.0,
            305.0,
            image=self.entry_image_2
        )
        self.entry_2 = Entry(
            show='*',
            bd=0,
            bg="#FFFFFF",
            highlightthickness=0
        )
        self.entry_2.place(
            x=503.0,
            y=290.0,
            width=170.0,
            height=28.0
        )


        self.button_image_1 = PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("button_1.png"))
        self.button_1 = Button(
            image=self.button_image_1,
            borderwidth=0,
            highlightthickness=0,
            command=self.login_user,
            relief="flat"
        )
        self.button_1.place(
            x=368.0,
            y=364.0,
            width=168.0,
            height=29.0
        )
    def login_user(self):

        '''Check username and password entered are correct'''
        if self.entry_1.get() == self.user and self.entry_2.get() == self.passw:
           SampleApp.switch_frame(self,InicialPage)  
        else:
            
            '''Prompt user that either id or password is wrong'''
            self.message = Label(text = 'Username or Password incorrect. Try again!',fg = 'Red')
            self.message.grid(row=6,column=2)

class InicialPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = Canvas(
            bg = "#F1F2F2",
            height = 549,
            width = 892,
            bd = 0,
            highlightthickness = 0,
            relief = "ridge"
        )

        self.canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)


        self.button_image_22 = PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("button_22.png"))
        self.button_22 = Button(
            image=self.button_image_22,
            borderwidth=0,
            highlightthickness=0,
            command=lambda: parent.switch_frame(MenuPage),
            relief="flat"
        )
        self.button_22.place(
            x=198.0,
            y=420.0,
            width=158.0,
            height=40.0
        )

        self.button_image_27 = PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("button_27.png"))
        self.button_27 = Button(
            image=self.button_image_27,
            borderwidth=0,
            highlightthickness=0,
            command=lambda: print("button_27 clicked"),
            relief="flat"
        )
        self.button_27.place(
            x=675.0,
            y=235.0,
            width=200.0,
            height=134.0
        )
```

There is another class, when i try use it, i got the same problem.

```
class MenuPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = Canvas(

            bg = "#F1F2F2",
            height = 549,
            width = 892,
            bd = 0,
            highlightthickness = 0,
            relief = "ridge"
        )
        self.canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)

        self.button_image_33 = PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("button_33.png"))
        self.button_33 = Button(
            image=self.button_image_33,
            borderwidth=0,
            highlightthickness=0,
            command=lambda: parent.switch_frame(InicialPage),
            relief="flat"
        )
        self.button_33.place(
            x=564.0,
            y=212.0,
            width=195.0,
            height=195.0
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

So, I need Help to not get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VENTAS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\VENTAS\Desktop\Alvaro\Asper\ALVARO\ASPER CODIGO\26.08.21\PORCLASES\proeba.py", line 137, in login_user
    SampleApp.switch_frame(self,InicialPage)
  File "c:\Users\VENTAS\Desktop\Alvaro\Asper\ALVARO\ASPER CODIGO\26.08.21\PORCLASES\proeba.py", line 28, in switch_frame
    if self._frame is not None:
AttributeError: 'LogInPage' object has no attribute '_frame'
```

Comment: Do we really need 15 Buttons, each requiring an image that *we don't have*, in order to exhibit the problem?  Reduce this to a [mcve], please.

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Comment: We also don't need so many other widgets. The example needs to be _minimal_.

Comment: I have to reduce some trash to try more understandable

Comment: The answer is pretty simple: you're trying to call code that references `self._frame` before you have initialized `self._frame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you passed instance of `LoginFrame` as `self` argument into `SampleApp.switch_frame()`, it expects instance of `SampleApp` instead.  So you should use instance of `SampleApp` to execute `switch_frame()`:

```
    def login_user(self):

        '''Check username and password entered are correct'''
        if self.entry_1.get() == self.user and self.entry_2.get() == self.passw:
           #SampleApp.switch_frame(self,InicialPage)  
           # self.master is instance of SampleApp
           self.master.switch_frame(InicialPage)
        else:
            '''Prompt user that either id or password is wrong'''
            self.message = Label(text = 'Username or Password incorrect. Try again!',fg = 'Red')
            self.message.grid(row=6,column=2)
```

Comment: Thanks, bro! That's was so useful